# Variables in build.gradle for NativeScript plugins

Tags: plugins, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, nativescript

I'm building a plugin for OneSignal and it requires an app ID and
google project number.

So in our `package.json` file in the project root, we have:

```
"nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.demo",
    "tns-ios": {
        "version": "2.2.1"
    },
    "tns-android": {
        "version": "2.2.0"
    }
},
```

In a plugins `build.gradle` we can access variables like `__PACKAGE__` and `${applicationId}`.

> Can we add a custom variable to the project's `package.json` object
>   and use it in the `build.gradle` file? If not, where can I find a list of possible variables to use?

For example:

```
"nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.demo",
    "OneSignalID": "2345-3245-2345-9087",
    "OneSignalProjectNumber": "342875320456",
    "tns-ios": {
        "version": "2.2.1"
    },
    "tns-android": {
        "version": "2.2.0"
    }
},
```

Then in `build.gradle` something like:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [
            manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
            onesignal_app_id: "${nativescript-OneSignalID}",
            onesignal_google_project_number: "${nativescript-OneSignalProjectNumber}"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment I think you may need to handle this manually. Here’s how the Firebase handles this scenario, for instance: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase#android. You can use a post-install script to avoid needing to manually store the change https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/commit/66063e8907069bc968dae917be7e9fc11ab38d1c.

Comment: No worries! Just curious. Thanks so much for the reference. Also the https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk is another good example of this.

Comment: Ah yeah, good example. I’ll also add that this would be an excellent feature to request on https://github.com/nativescript/nativescript-cli/issues, as this isn’t the first time this has come up, and it would be great to have an automated solution.